# oracle database connection dynamically using ADOConnection in delphi

Tags: delphi

I am using delphi 7 and oracle. I want to connect oracle dynamically through delphi using TADOConnection. I have created one form containing 3 edit box for server name,username, password and one button 'Connect'. I tried to connect statically by building ConnectionString. Now i am trying to connect on 'Connect' button click depending upon the user enter values in server,username and password. 
How can i do this. any suggestions. thanks for the help.

Comment: IMHO should should better forget about using a ADO/OleDB connection with Oracle. There are severe problems with the providers from Microsoft or Oracle, about BLOBs and performance. Use instead direct OCI communication for lighter and faster access. See commercial versions like ODAC or our [Open Source classes](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/07/09/SynDBOracle%3A-Open-Source-native-Oracle-access).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the `ConnectionString` property of `TAdoConnection` component, you can get the right one from [ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle#p15) website

Here's the one for ADO connection with Microsoft provider:

```
Provider =msdaora; Data Source =MyOracleDB; User Id =myUsername; Password =myPassword;
```

for the UserID & Password, you have to replace them with your Editboxes.

**Update:**

for code you write something like this:

```
AdoConnection.Close;
AdoConnection.ConnectionString := format('Provider=msdaora; Data Source =MyOracleDB; User Id = %s; Password = %s',edtUserName.Text,edtPassword.Text]);
';
AdoConnection.Open;
```

Comment: after connection string to open Connection, we have to make ADOConnection.Connected:= true; right??

Comment: Do not use MS Oracle provider, as it supports only OCI7 and because that is limited in many ways. Use Oracle provider for Oracle.

Comment: And better to work with Oracle using 3d party libraries, like AnyDAC. Because ADO is limiting Oracle features.

Comment: @ oodesigner: I am unable to see any option like oracle provider for oracle. Need to install it??  I am currently using MSDAORA.

Comment: @Mohammed Nasman, yes, you need to download it from Oracle site and install. See the Hasan S answer.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong to get negative vote here :-/, @oodesigner, naren who asked about the oracle provider not me, I usually use ODAC not ado for connecting to oracle which is much better than ADO.

Comment: @Mohammed Nasman, i have downvoted for MSDAORA really. Why - i explained above.

Comment: @oodesigner, it's doesn't deserve a down vote, because I didn't give a wrong answer, I just gave me an example how to use connectionstring, with link for using MS or Oracle providers.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you already install the oracle client (Oracle Provide for OLEDB), have a working tnsnames, etc. So, for example, to connect to instance "ORCL" login as user "HR" with password "password", the connection string should be like :

> Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Data Source=ORCL;User
>   ID=HR;Password=password

And taking the string from the component, it will looks like :

```
Procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOConnection1.ConnectionString:= 'Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;' +
    'Data Source=' + Edit1.Text + ';' + 
    'Data Source=' + Edit2.Text + ';' + 
    'Password=' + Edit3.Text;
  ADOConnection1.LoginPrompt:= False;
  ADOConnection1.Connected:= True;
end;
```